# Changing taskbar tray icon. C++ MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, icons

I am finishing a C++ MFC application and wish to update the icon that is shown in the bottom taskbar for Windows.  I am using Visual Studio  I have found the .ico file in VS.  I removed or updated all versions of the MFC logo.

[image: Example MFC Icon]

When my program first starts, the above image is shown as the icon.  When I log in and load the second form, I get my icon:

[image: My Icon]

I am trying to find out why the first form reverts to the old MFC icon.  In my .ico file, I can find no trace of the MFC icon.  Thanks.

Comment: Windows has an icon cache for applications that is hard to reset. Search for ways to do it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: To everyone having a problem with this, make sure you Rebuild your solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An MFC application always displays its own ICON for application and dialog.. you can change it by replacing the icon file for the resource called IDR_MAINFRAME

SetIcon sets the icon on the dialog title bar (small icon) and when you use Alt-tab (big icon)

The icons you see in the Windows Explorer are the main Application Icons (the icon with the lowest ID in your rc file).

As [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) suggested, you can have a look at: http://www.winability.com/repair-windows-desktop-icon-cache/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run

ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache

from a DOS Command window. You can change properties of IDR_MAINFRAME in the Resource view or edit the .rc file in the text editor, then re-compile resources by right-clicking on the .rc file or use CTRL+F7. These are all the changes necessary when changin the default MFC icon in an MFC Visual Studio 20155 application.